# intellej shared workspace between my Windows-based laptop and Macbook

Tags: java, windows, macos

I have a shared workspace between my Windows-based laptop and Macbook, today when I wanted to work with my Mac on the project that I got used to working on Windows, I faced this error in the compilation:

> error running 'pfpmapplication': 'c:/program files/java/jre1.8.0_144' is not a valid jre home in macos

Would you please let me know what should I do to resolve this problem?

Please note that I checked for the SDK address in my project and it is correctly adjusted to the Mac JDK, but I could not find the 'C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101' anywhere in my project structure!

Comment: Well in the first place I wouldn't share a workspace. Why would you do that in the age of git? Leads to just this type of problems.
Have you tried reimporting the project? This is probably somewhere in the .idea files..

Answer (score 0):

You can try searching the string "C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101" using find in files function of a text editor such as Sublime Text on the project folder and replace with the correct path.

Another way can be deleting all the Idea project's file and folders and reimport on mac. Please note that such files shouldn't be included in Source control (GIT, SVN...)